# Making a spider crawl websites

Tags: java, web, html

I am trying to make a java class that fetches words and links of a specific page. Let us say the page is stackoverflow.com. I want the class to first check and store all the links on that page. After It has stored and checked all links on that page I want it to branch out to every page within the first page and then check all the links again until it has branched out completely and checked all links. I only managed to branch it out to the second set of links. Here is the code:

```
  public void spiderLeg(String webAdress){
  public HashSet < String > getLink = new HashSet <String>();
    a = new Reader(webAdress);
    a.run();
    System.out.println("CRAWLING");
    for(String s : a.getLinks()){
        getLink.add(s);
        a = new Reader(s);
        a.run();

        for(String v : a.getLinks()){
            getLink.add(v);
            a = new Reader(v);
            a.run();
        }
        for(String h : l.getLinks()){
            getLink.add(h);
        }

    }


}
```

As you see I can only make it branch out to a second set of links. I want it to branch out until there no longer is any links that have not been visited. I just don't see how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a recursive operation, not a loop operation.

If `s` is an address just like the one originally passed to the method, then recursively call the method with `s`.  Something like this:

```
public void spiderLeg(String webAdress){
    public HashSet < String > getLink = new HashSet <String>();
    a = new Reader(webAdress);
    a.run();
    System.out.println("CRAWLING");
    for(String s : a.getLinks()){
        getLink.add(s);
        a = new WebPageReader(s);
        a.run();

        spiderLeg(s); // <-- here
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to know or control how "deep" the series of links gets.  Each page will call the same method on the "next" set of links.

Note that you're *definitely* going to want to add some more conditions to this code.  Blindly recursing over all found links carries a *huge* risk of infinitely recursing.  Consider what happens when `Page A` has a link to `Page B`, and `Page B` in turn has a link to `Page A`.  It may not even be that obvious, there could be several pages in between.  And the links may not be identical.

As a thought exercise, consider a page with a table of records that can be paged back and forth.  Each "page" is going to have links to the previous and next pages, as well as several numbered pages in between.  So there will be many links back and forth between all of the pages.  And those links *might not* be identical strings, they could pass all sorts of query string arguments to each other.

In general, you're probably going to have a bit of trial and error to answer the question "Have I already visited this page in this process?"  You may even want to add a "maximum depth" to the recursion to avoid infinite recursion.  It would basically be an additional argument to the method which increments every time and compares against a constant.  It could be something as simple as this:

```
public void spiderLeg(String webAdress, int depth){

    // check against a "max depth constant"
    if (depth > 10){
        return;
    }

    public HashSet < String > getLink = new HashSet <String>();
    a = new Reader(webAdress);
    a.run();
    System.out.println("CRAWLING");
    for(String s : a.getLinks()){
        getLink.add(s);
        a = new WebPageReader(s);
        a.run();

        spiderLeg(s, depth + 1); // increment the depth
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** It looks like your `getLink` variable also needs to be moved to a higher scope.  This is because every recursive call to this method is going to have its own copy of that variable, so every call will have exactly *one* element in that `HashSet`.  Instead, make it a class-level member.  Something like this:

```
private HashSet < String > getLink = new HashSet <String>();

public void spiderLeg(String webAdress, int depth){

    // check against a "max depth constant"
    if (depth > 10){
        return;
    }

    a = new Reader(webAdress);
    a.run();
    System.out.println("CRAWLING");
    for(String s : a.getLinks()){
        getLink.add(s);
        a = new WebPageReader(s);
        a.run();

        spiderLeg(s, depth + 1); // increment the depth
    }
}
```

That way each recursive call to the method adds to the same `HashSet`, rather than creating its own.

---

**Edit:** Based on ongoing comments, it looks like this needs to be simplified a little further.  Something like this, perhaps?:

```
private HashSet < String > getLink = new HashSet <String>();

public void spiderLeg(String webAdress, int depth){

    // recursion terminating condition, check for maximum depth
    if (depth > 10){
        return;
    }

    // perform operation on this node
    getLink.add(webAdress);
    a = new Reader(webAdress);
    a.run();
    System.out.println("CRAWLING");

    // recurse on next nodes
    for(String s : a.getLinks()){
        spiderLeg(s, depth + 1); // increment the depth
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and only one page is getting added each time spiderLeg gets called on. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: @DanZoe: Define "getting added".  Is the method call recursing?  Note that you *may* need to pull some values into a higher scope.  For example, `getLink` is only ever going to contain the one link for that one method call.  If you want it to collect all of the links, it's going to have to be a class-level member, or perhaps be passed to the recursive method calls as a reference argument.

Comment: I want the getLink HashSet to contain all of the links that are being gathered.

Comment: @DanZoe: The simplest approach is probably to make that variable a class-level member.  I've updated the answer to describe this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive, you are suggesting a depth first search if I understood correctly, but you could also do breadth first and eliminate the duplicates each level. What you will have to do anyway, otherwise you will be running around in circles, e.g. using a hash.

Comment: @maraca: Without knowing the depth it's still going to have to be a recursive operation.  True, this will add values to `getLink` depth-first rather than breadth-first.  Though ideally it shouldn't matter the order in which items are added to the collection, querying the collection is where sorting becomes more important.  (Which entirely depends on how this data is queried and used, which we don't know.)

Comment: @David I made it a class level member. It still only adds the same link to the HashSet. When I remove the spiderLeg() call it starts fetches data again. But only on the first level of the webpage.

Comment: simply put, the alternative: while (new links were discovered) { follow the newly found links, e.g. use a list for the links discovered each iteration}

Comment: @DanZoe: I can't really debug this for you.  When you step through in the debugger, what happens in the recursive call?  Is the method called again?  Is it given the new address?  Where specifically does it fail?

Comment: @David The method seems to be called again. I might have failed to tell you that a.run() gets ALL of the links in one page, not only one. So the first value of keeps getting assigned to the HashSet everytime the spiderLeg method gets called.

Comment: @DanZoe: Well, your original code invoked `a.Run()` twice, so I was just preserving that.  It sounds like it doesn't need to be included in the loop, though.  I'm obviously not familiar with all of the side-effects you need this code to produce.  But it sounds like you want to add `webAddress` to `getLinks` *outside* of the loop, and then within the loop all you should need to do is call the method recursively.

Comment: @David Could you please update your answer so I can see clearly how you do it? I am sorry for asking such a moronic question to begin with, it is just that I have been struggling with this a long time now.

Comment: @DanZoe: I've updated the answer with another version.  This time I've also included comments to separate out the three key components to a recursive operation, to attempt to clarify what it's doing.  Picture this as essentially a tree structure, where the method is called once for each node on the tree.

Comment: @David Now only two links gets added to the HashSet. I cannot see how this is not working...

Comment: @DanZoe: This really isn't an effective method of debugging.  You're going to have to step through your code in a debugger and see what's happening, I can't do that for you from here.